# SAS displays a value longer than the column's length

Tags: sas

I have a column with a length of `8`. However, when I view the data, the value in the column is above `8` characters long.

See the following screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLe4T.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing up Length and Format. 
http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2007/11/20/lengths-and-formats-the-long-and-short-of-it/

> Length: The column length, in SAS terms, is the amount of storage allocated in the data set to hold the column values. The length is specified in bytes. For numeric columns, the valid lengths are usually 3 through 8. The longer the length, the greater the precision allowed within the column values. For character columns, the length can be 1 through 32767. For single-byte data values, that equates to the number of characters the column can hold. For multibyte data values (DBCS, Unicode, or UTF-8), where a character can occupy more than one byte, the number of characters that fit might be less than the length value of the column.
>
> Format: The column format, in SAS terms, is a basically an instruction for how to transform a raw value into an appearance that is suitable for a given purpose. A basic attribute of a format is the format length, which controls how much of the value is displayed. For example, a character column might have a storage length of 10 bytes, but a format length of 5 characters ($5. format), so when you see the formatted values you will see at most 5 characters for each record.